# Javascript - Prefill the input field by checking the previous data and increment by 1 or increment with any sequence number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We have one column named CandidateID in database which has some data like shown below :-
[image]
We have one addbutton where it will open a modal to fill up the details like shown below :-
[image]

Here when we click on add button the candidate ID input field should autofill the value with next sequence ie KP05 (if the last candid is KP04 ). Or else any random number is fine too which is unique everytime when we click on add button

is it possible to do in javascript? if yes , how can i do it? or 
Is there any way to set a field to display  a sequential number string? need to prefill a unique random number each time in the input field when  the add modal ie Dialog is opened 
Add button : -

```
 <button class="btn btn-default pull pull-right" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addMember" id="addMemberModalBtn">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Member
            </button>
```

Html code for Candidate Input field

```
   <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"  role="dialog" id="addMember">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span> Add Member</h4>
      </div>
   <div class="modal-body">


        <button type="reset" id="searchclear" class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>

          <div class="form-group">
          <!--/here teh addclass has-error will appear -->
          <div class="col-sm-5"> 
            <label for="candid" >Candidate ID</label>
            <br>

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="candid" name="candid" placeholder="candid" >
            <!-- here the text will apper  -->
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="mobile">Mobile</label><span id="mobile_status"></span> 
            <br>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="mobile" value="+91" onkeyup="checkmobile();" >
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label for="email" >Email</label><span id="email_status"></span>    
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onkeyup="checkemail();">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Looks like you've forgotten to post the code you already have for the task.

Comment: @Teemu Yes i have posted my code now. I have not implemented it . I wanted to know how we can do it .

Answer (score 0):

If your last candidate id is available, you can increment the Id as following way

```
var num = "KPO4"; //Assuming this will be last candidate id
alert("KPO" + (parseInt(num.replace(/\D/g, '')) + 1));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#buttonId").click(function(){
$.ajax({url: "Controller/Method", success: function(result){
    $("#txtCandidateId").val(result).attr("disabled","disabled");
}});
});
```

DATABASE Query
SELECT MAX(CandidateId)+1 FROM TableName